# Problems with CGI Script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, perl, cgi

A user has to type some text into a text field which is declared as a form in my HTML. Some JavaScript code prints the user's input which has been processed by a CGI script.

#### JavaScript

```javascript
function xmlHttpPost(strURL) {var xmlHttpReq;
// Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
// IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    xmlHttpReq.timeout = 0;
    xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-    urlencoded');
    xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            updatepage(xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
    }
    var form = document.forms['f1'];
    var query = form.word.value;
    xmlHttpReq.send("key=" + query);
}

function updatepage(str){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result:" + "<br/>" + str;
}
```

#### CGI

```perl
#!"G:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use CGI;

$query = new CGI;
$key = $query->param('key');
print $query->header;
print "<h1>The key is $key</h1>"
```

When I type something into the form and submit the data Error 500 occurs:

> End of script output before headers: ajax-echo.cgi

This is what Apache's error.log says

> AH01215: Can't locate CGI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: .) at G:/xampp/cgi-bin/ajax-echo.cgi line 7.\r, referer: http://localhost/ajax.html?word=test
>   AH01215: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at G:/xampp/cgi-bin/ajax-echo.cgi line 7.\r, referer: http://localhost/ajax.html?word=test

There's a newly installed and configured XAMPP installation on my USB stick. It has every permission it needs to run properly.

Comment: `application/x-www-form-    urlencoded` is that a typo HERE ONLY or also in your real code?

Comment: On the command line, if you type`perl -e 'use CGI;'` can it find the module? Another possibility is dos vs unix line endings... I mention this because of the suspicious "\r" in the error output... you could try doing a `dos2unix` (or `unix2dos`) on your cgi script to see if it helps.

Comment: The obvious answer is that the perl installation on your server doesn't have the `CGI` module installed. It hasn't been a core module since v5.22 was released in June 2015.

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the error message is this:

```
Can't locate CGI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: .)
```

The search path for modules just contains the current directory "." and obviously there is no CGI.pm in the current directory.

Try to find the directory, where CGI.pm is installed, and then add this line to your Apache configuration

```
SetEnv PERL5LIB "G:/xampp/path/to/module/directory"
```